# This particular usage of はたまた after the subject

Tags: words

I sometimes encounter sentences such as:

> 不安ははたまた無邪気な夜に簡単に消されるのだ。

> 妄言はいつまで長々お喋り 公然の噂がはたまた目隠し、

> それははたまた何百年後の話か？

But I have no idea what “はたまた” means here. I know it can be used essentially synonymously with “”それとも” or “あるいは” but neither make sense there.

Comment: The last one seems the least bad simply because it's a question. The first one might be a misuse for またしても or something. The second one makes absolutely no sense to me, and はたまた is not the only reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はたまた in the first two examples make almost no sense to me even after reading the entire lyrics (from [here](https://www.uta-net.com/song/280608/) and [here](https://piapro.jp/t/hWx5)). In particular, the lyrics of the latter song are nearly a word salad, so you shouldn't try to interpret them seriously.

As for the third one, I think it's simply working as a dramatic or pretentious version of あるいは. It can be translated as "Or else".

Comment: I wouldn't really understand it with “あるいは” either. Is it simply the case that that “はたまた” could also come at the start of the sentence, as in “or else, how many years from now will it happen?”

Comment: @Zorf The sentence is the same as "はたまたそれは何百年後の話か". This 何百年 is probably not "how many hundreds of years" but "hundreds of years". So it's like "(Is it a story of the present?) Or else, is it a story of the distant future?"